# Multilabel Image Classification - problem with probability at prediction

Tags: image-classification, computer-vision, multilabel-classification, image

I'm building a multilabel image classification problem usinc MIMIC CXR dataset. I'm struggling with probability at prediction as for every image in test dataset the probability of an existance of label is the same. It means that everytime I run prediction I get for example 0.57 for label X for every image in test dataset.

I tried multiple architectures and adjusted the learning rate but it did not help.
I'm trying the approach of adjusting state-of-art achitectures by switching to sigmoid activation function on last Dense layer with num of class because transfering the multilabel classification to binary/multi class classification problem is not performing.

I use images and I one-hot labels to [0,0,1,0,1] form.

Let me know if you have any additional questions which might help. I'm really annoyed as I spent multiple weeks trying to make it work and I'm out of ideas.

Thanks in advance,
Greg